# how to forward fill non-null values in a pandas dataframe based on a set condition

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,0,1,0,0], 'b':[0,0,1,0,0,0], 'c':[0,1,1,0,0,0]})
df.index = pd.date_range('2000-03-02', periods=6, freq='D')
```

which looks like this:

```
            a  b  c
2000-03-02  0  0  0
2000-03-03  0  0  1
2000-03-04  0  1  1
2000-03-05  1  0  0
2000-03-06  0  0  0
2000-03-07  0  0  0
```

And now I want to set to 2 each value in a given column that occurs *after* the last 1. The desired result looks like this:

```
            a  b  c
2000-03-02  0  0  0
2000-03-03  0  0  1
2000-03-04  0  1  1
2000-03-05  2  2  2
2000-03-06  2  2  2
2000-03-07  2  2  2
```

I've got this code, which works:

```
cols = df.columns
for col in cols:
    s = df[col]
    x = s[s==1].index[-1]
    df[col][(x + 1):] = 2
```

But it seems pretty awkward and contrary to the spirit of pandas (un-Pandonic?). Any suggestions for better approaches?

Comment: pandastic / pandalicious / pandorable ... ahem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the lower zeros with NaNs:

```
In [11]: df.replace(0, np.nan).bfill()  # maybe neater way to do this?
Out[11]:
             a   b   c
2000-03-02   1   1   1
2000-03-03   1   1   1
2000-03-04   1   1   1
2000-03-05   1 NaN NaN
2000-03-06 NaN NaN NaN
2000-03-07 NaN NaN NaN
```

Now you can use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to change these to 2:

```
In [12]: df.where(df.replace(0, np.nan).bfill(), 2)
Out[12]:
            a  b  c
2000-03-02  0  0  0
2000-03-03  0  0  1
2000-03-04  0  1  1
2000-03-05  1  2  2
2000-03-06  2  2  2
2000-03-07  2  2  2
```

Edit: it may be faster to use a trick here with cumsum:

```
In [21]: %timeit df.where(df.replace(0, np.nan).bfill(), 2)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.34 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit df.where(df[::-1].cumsum()[::-1], 2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.7 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.where(np.cumsum(df.values[::-1], 0)[::-1], df.values, 2), df.index)
10000 loops, best of 3: 186 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty general soln. (e.g.  your will fail if the index is non-consecutive). 
The first part, getting the indexer is pretty pandastic!

```
In [64]: indexer = Series(df.index.get_indexer(df.diff().idxmin().values),index=df.columns)

In [65]: indexer
Out[65]: 
a    4
b    3
c    3
dtype: int64
```

I think their is a vectorized way of doing this, all you have to do is construct the correct boolean matrix based on the above indexer, but making my brain hurt.

```
In [66]: def f(x):
    x.iloc[indexer[x.name]:] = 2
    return x
   ....: 

In [67]: df.apply(f)
Out[67]: 
            a  b  c
2000-03-02  0  0  0
2000-03-03  0  0  1
2000-03-04  0  1  1
2000-03-05  1  2  2
2000-03-06  2  2  2
2000-03-07  2  2  2

[6 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: One trick is to use cumsum (note: we're missing an ascending arg in cumsum!), can't think how to vectorize properly.